# Concavity of a function at different intervals

Tags: calculus

I have a function $f(x)=\frac{-2}{x+1}+\frac{x^2}{2}-2x$. I know there is a vertical asymptote at $x=-1$. I need to determine where the graph is concave up and concave down. I am told to consider the cases either side of the vertical asymptote separately.

I found the second derivative and solved it for x when it equals zero $\frac{-4}{(x+1)^3}+1=0$ and found $x=\sqrt[3]{4}-1$. I'm not sure how to use this to figure out the concavity for intervals either side of the vertical asymptote. I can see it graphically but not sure how to prove it mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

You want to analyze the second derivative function to determine which values of $x$ will result in $f''(x) < 0$ and which values of $x$ result in $f''(x) > 0$.

The easiest way to do this and ensure that you don't miss any important behavior is to first single out any points where $f''$ may change sign. This may happen at any point where $f''(x)=0$ or $f''(x)$ does not exist.

You have found that $f''(x)=0$ for $x=4^{1/3}-1$. Also, $f''$ doesn't exist at $x=-1$. So, you should plug in to $f''(x)$ an $x$ value in each of the intervals $(-\infty,-1)$, $(-1, 4^{1/3}-1)$, and $(4^{1/3}-1, \infty)$. You know that on these intervals, the sign of $f''(x)$ won't change, and so you will have determined the sign of $f''(x)$ for all $x$.